# C++ Vector Subscript out of Range Error 1221

Tags: c++, vector

I am trying to make a program that recieves numbers from the user, and then rearranges the from least to greatest. I am using vectors (which I just learned about), and it gives me a subscript out of range error. I am not able to find what part of the code gives me this error, so hopefully someone more knowledgeable on vector and c++ can find it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void order(int a, int b);
void orderRev(int a, int b);

int main() {

vector<int> num;
bool going = true;

do {
    cout << "\nEnter a number or type 'x' to order:" << endl;
    string reply;
    getline(cin, reply);
    if (reply != "x") {
        int a = atoi(reply.c_str());
        num.push_back(a);
        cout << "\nYou currently have " << num.size() << " numbers added." << endl;
    }
    else {
        going = false;
    }
} while (going);

for (int i = 0; i < num.size(); i++) {
        order(num[i], num[i + 1]);
    }

for (int i = num.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    orderRev(num[i + 1], num[i]);
}

cout << "\nThe number you entered in order from least to greatest are: " << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < num.size(); i++) {
    cout << num[i] << " ";
}


void order(int a, int b) {
    if (a > b) {
        int c = b;
        b = a;
        a = c;
    }
}

void orderRev(int a, int b) {
    if (a < b) {
        int c = b;
        b = a;
        a = c;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Fix these lines to this:

```
// added the -1 as this will now go up to the 2nd to last element
// for `n`, and the last element for `n+1`
for (int i = 0; i < num.size() - 1; i++) {
    order(num[i], num[i + 1]);
}

// changed the starting number to size -2 (for the same reasoning)
for (int i = num.size() - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
    orderRev(num[i + 1], num[i]);
}
```

Why does this need to be this way? Think about how indices in C++ work. They are zero-indexed! That means that if you want both the element and the one in front of it, you must go up to the size of the vector minus 1. Hence, for a vector of 10 items (size 10), at i == 9 your code will work like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < num.size(); i++) {
  // i = 9
  order(num[9], num[9+1]);// index 10 does not exist! Hence, you really need to go up to num.size() - 1!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Vectors index start with `0`. index will be `0` to `n-1` , if you use `num[i + 1]` it will exceed the vector size, if you don't check in loop condition.

Your code has more than one flaw. The output will be same as the input , hint: know the difference between pass by reference and pass by value and after that check some sorting algorithms.